# How to load KML/KMZ data files externally in cesium-resium

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, cesiumjs

I am doing a react project and I used resium library which is react version of cesium library. In there, I need to load kml files which are downloaded from server in run time. Which means I need to load kml files in run time.

as an example, client app receive some kml data file from server through an API call, then I need to show that KML/KMZ file data into the resium world map. So I need to load kml files externally. I tried some codes but it does not work. Could you please check my code and let me know how to load KML or KMZ files out side of  tag. I could able to load kml files inside  tag successfully. But I need to load kml files outside of  tag. please refer my code.

```
import './App.css';
import { hot } from "react-hot-loader/root";

import React, { createRef } from "react";
import { Viewer, KmlDataSource} from "resium";


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = createRef();
  }

  loadKmlFileExternal() {
    if (this.ref.current && this.ref.current.cesiumElement) {
       //I tried two code syntax but no lucky. 
      <this.ref.current.cesiumElement>
        <KmlDataSource data={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/kml/gdpPerCapita2008.kmz"} />;
      </this.ref.current.cesiumElement>
      //or
      this.ref.current.cesiumElement.dataSources.add(KmlDataSource.load(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/kml/gdpPerCapita2008.kmz"));
    }
  }


  render() {
    let content = null;

    content = (
      <Viewer full ref={this.ref} >
        <KmlDataSource data={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/kml/facilities/facilities.kml"} /> // This works, but I need to load outside from Viewer
      </Viewer>
    );

    return (      
      <div>
        {content}
        {this.loadKmlFileExternal()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default `hot(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what does your API return? I think you do not need API. All you need is to upload your KML file into your server and use its URL.